# Is it plausible to create a .Net app which functions as a simple database?

Tags: .net, sqlite

I need a relatively simple utility that permits me to work with and share data between a custom .Net app and a Python notebook.  I thought SQLite would probably be ideal for this given its popularity in the Python world and considering the support it has among numerable open-source database management utilities.  And it does suit that purpose as long as I'm using a shared SQLite database file.

But if I wanted to make this a portable and re-usable utility to be shared with other coworkers, having to deal with the db file becomes a little bit of a hassle.  It's my understanding that an in-memory instance of an SQLite database cannot be shared between processes even if the processes share memory, so I cannot eliminate the need of a file that way.  A RAM drive seems a little over the top, and potentially complicated w.r.t. portability. Other forms of IPC should be possible, but may exclude the possibility of either my notebook or my .Net app from being able to interface with the SQLite db directly.

That led me to wonder if I can produce a .Net app as a utility which functions as a wrapper for SQLite, as a *hopefully* simple local SQLite server which a locally running Python notebook could connect to.

It's a thought I've never explored so I'm in search of the internet's guidance on this one, or on better solutions.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I like Sqlite for its portability, but for shared applications it's limited. You could look into a distributed SQLite solution. Your application could create local instance and join a "cluster" but I haven't played enough with it to say what the downfalls are.

https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite

Unless you have an API frontend talking to a single instance of a db file sitting locally, sharing data will become problematic. SQL, even SQL Express may be a simpler solution.